# Unexpected double value in c#

Tags: c#, .net, double

Today i come with a problem and not able to figure out what is the issue with this simple statement

I Tried

```
double d =1/4;
```

expected ans for me is `0.25` but in reality ans is `0.0` why so ??

And what should we do if statement is in terms of integer variables like this

```
double a =(a-b)/(d+e);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because what you done is here *integer division*. `1 / 4` always give you `0` as a result regardless which type you assing it.

.NET has 3 type of division. From [`7.7.2 Division operator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691373%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

- Integer division
- Floating-point division
- Decimal division

From *Integer division* part;

> The division rounds the result towards zero, and the absolute value of
>   the result is the largest possible integer that is less than the
>   absolute value of the quotient of the two operands.

If you want to `0.25` as a result, you should define one of your values as a floating point.

You can use one of these;

```
double d = 1d / 4d;
double d = 1d / 4;
double d = 1 / 4d;
```

> And what should we do if statement is in terms of integer variables
>   like this
>
> double a =(a-b)/(d+e);

I assume your `a`, `b`, `d` and `e` are integers, you should use one of these then;

```
double a = (double)(a-b) / (double)(d+e);
double a = (a-b) / (double)(d+e);
double a = (double)(a-b) / (d+e);
```

Comment: What should we do if w have statements in terms of integer variables like this double a=(a-b)/(d+c)

Comment: @HotCoolStud I updated my answer. Take a look.

Answer (score 2):

```
double d =1d/4;
```

should work. 
If you don't specify the type of your numbers, it is treated as Integer. And integer 1/4 will be zero.

Comment: What should we do if w have statements in terms of integer variables like this double a=(a-b)/(d+c);

Comment: cast at least one side to double?

Answer (score 1):

/ Operator ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3b1ff23f.aspx))

> When you divide two integers, the result is always an integer. For
>   example, the result of 7 / 3 is 2. To determine the remainder of 7 /
>   3, use the remainder operator (%). To obtain a quotient as a rational
>   number or fraction, give the dividend or divisor type **float** or type
>   **double**. You can assign the type implicitly if you express the dividend
>   or divisor as a decimal by putting a digit to the right side of the
>   decimal point.

Try this:

```
double d = 1.0 / 4.0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
double d = (double) 1 / 4;
```